# Conflict between use of hx:fileupload and tomahawk tree2 component in the application

Tags: jsf, web.xml, myfaces, websphere-8, tomahawk

I'm using **hx:fileupload** component which allows the user to open local file system and browse to the file. In the same application I have used **tomahawk tree2** component to display hierarchical directory structure.

Earlier to adding tree2 component, fileupload was working perfect but when I added the filter tag corresponding to tomahawk tree2 in **web.xml** file,    ***getFileupload1().getFilename()*** method of hx:fileupload component *(where getFileupload1() is getter method of hx:fileupload component)* return null exception.

**Filter tag code:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If i **remove filter tag** from web.xml file, **fileupload** component resumes to work properly but **Tree2** component won't work.

Please help to make both components work together in the application.

Thank you

**I have done the following updations:**

1. Implemented ExtensionsFilter filter servlet by removing **if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(httpRequest)) {} block** from the original ExtensionsFilter source code file.

**updated web.xml code**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>pagecode.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExtensionsFilter` also automatically parses `multipart/form-data` requests as part of its job for Tomahawk's `<t:inputFileUpload>`. This is not disableable by configuration.

You have basically 2 options:

1. Copy the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk/tomahawk12/1.1.14/org/apache/myfaces/webapp/filter/ExtensionsFilter.java#ExtensionsFilter) of `ExtensionsFilter` under the same license and remove the whole `if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(httpRequest)) {}` block (lines 347-350) so that it doesn't parse `multipart/form-data` requests anymore and use this filter instead.
2. Replace `<hx:fileUpload>` by `<t:inputFileUpload>`.

Comment: I used first approach it causes hx:fileupload to work properly but call to page with tree2 component throws  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ExtensionsFilter not correctly configured. Resource mapping missing. Resources cant be delivered. Please see: http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/extensionsFilter.html

Comment: You need to add a filter mapping on resources as per example in the given link.

Comment: Please check the updated question. Code formatting is not working. Please clarify which link i got to refer for resources mapping. Thanks.

Comment: Gosh, based on Tomahawk source code, it's manually parsing `web.xml` and explicitly checking if it finds a filter with class FQN `org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter` and throwing this error when absent :| You'll have to rename your filter to have exactly the same package and class name (and keep it in your webapp project so that it ends up in `/WEB-INF/classes` and so gets precedence in classloading over the one in any JAR, so don't put it in a JAR).

Comment: Got the solution and my application is now up and running. Obliged.:)